# Hiding a t:graphicImage based on h:inputText disabled value

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have an input text field **(h:inputText)** for user to enter date and a image link next to it **(t:graphic)** which is a popup calendar.

I am able to disable the h:inputText based on the users role by calling back bean function **userFieldBean** and get value of boolean **showField** and disable the textfield accordingly.

```
<h:inputText id="d1" value="txt1" disabled="#{userFieldsBean.showField}"/>
```

I also want to hide or at least disable the popup calendar link if the textfield next to is disabled, but since to hide the t:graphic i need to set the style as **Style=display:none** i have trouble figuring out how i should do it.

Is it possible to do something like

```
<t:graphic url="/imgs/cal.gif" id="img1" Style="if("#{userFieldsBean.showField}"==true) return "display:none" else "return:block"".
```

The above is obviously wrong but i put it in there as I am curious to know the possibilities.

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the t:graphicImage you are using a tomahawk component? If so there is a rendered attribute on the component, you cam do the following:

```
<t:graphicImage rendered="#{userFieldsBean.showField}" ...
```

If you have to set a style you should be able to do something like:

```
<t:graphicImage style="#{userFieldsBean.showField ? 'display:none' : 'display:block'}" ...
```

Comment: That's exactly what i needed, Thank you so much for helping me out. It works as expected.